# Quiero cambiar el valor de un atributo booleano al hacer click en un boton con Djando, pasando el id del elemento que quiero cambiar por url

Tags: ajax, django, booleano

Estoy tratando de cambiar el valor de atributo de un objeto, usando ajax. La verdad no tengo claro por que no funciona. De hecho no se si lo estoy haciendo bien. Les muestro lo que tengo hecho:
Este es el script ajax:

```
$("#change_state").on('click', function () {
      var url = $("#changeStatus").attr("data-orden-status");
      var orden = $(this).val();
      var archivado = true // or false, you have to set it
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
          'archivado': archivado,
          'orden': orden,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.success) {
            alert("ajax call success.");
            // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
          }else{
            alert("ajax call not success.");
          }
        }
      });

    });
```

Este es mi view:

```
def ajax_change_status(request):
    orden_id = request.GET.get('orden')
    orden = OrdenDeTrabajo.objects.get(id=orden_id)
    try:
        orden.archivado = False
        orden.save()
        return JsonResponse({"success": False})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"success": True})
    return JsonResponse('No se que onda')
```

En html trato de invocarlo asi:

```
<form id="changeStaus" method="POST" class="form"
    data-orden-status="{% url 'ordenesTrabajo:ajax_change_status' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="change_state">Archivar orden</button>
</form>
```

Y en URLs puse:

```
path('ajax/change_status/', views.ajax_change_status, name='ajax_change_status')
```

Yo en la pagina que estaría en el momento de que este funcione ya tiene el id en la url, porque es una plantilla en la cual estoy mostrando el contenido de un objeto. Usando otro ajax, pero esos ajax solo muestran, no hacen cambios a la base de datos. Espero que se entienda cual es mi problema, sino, no duden en preguntarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu ajax lo tienes en el mismo html? osea en el DJango template?
Si es así que tal si intentamos lo siguiente:

```
$("#change_state").on('click', function () {
  var url = "{{ajax_change_status}}?order={{object.pk}}"
  var archivado = true // or false, you have to set it
  $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: url,
    data: {
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
      'archivado': archivado,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        alert("ajax call success.");
        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
      }else{
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
    }
  });
```

object.pk, sería el id del elemento que le des clic, claro, habría que ver el la vista que tienes en la cual mandas el template.
Espero haber dado a enternder. Si necesitas algo más o no me expliqué avisame.

Comment: De hecho tenia el ajax en otro documento y lo invocaba en el html, pero eso no debería ser problema, uso otros scripts en ese archivo en otro html y funcionan, nada mas que no otro los uso solo para mostrar info en pantalla, no editan nada. De todos modos, probé ponerlo en el mismo html, cuando hago click en el button, me sale la pantalla del navegador diciendo "Esta pagina no funciona", lo probe con tu script.